# Update with Values in Spring JPA Native Query for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to achieve below using Spring JPA.

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a
from (values
    ('123', 1),
    ('345', 2) // this will be dynamic
) as c(column_b, column_a) 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

Is there a way to pass the values from spring jpa using native query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you first serialize your dynamic data as text representing  a JSON array of any length - or even an empty one - like this

```json
[
 [1, "234"],
 [2, "345"]
]
```

and use this native query passing the above text as a single parameter:

```java
@Query(
value = "update test as t set column_a = c.column_a
         from (
          select j[0]\\:\\:integer column_a, j[1]\\:\\:text column_b
          from jsonb_array_elements (?1\\:\\:jsonb) j
         ) c
         where c.column_b = t.column_b",
nativeQuery = true
)
void updateFunction(String dynamicJSONData);
```

Notes:

- In JPA the postfix cast operator `::` is escaped as `\\:\\:`;
- Under PostgreSQL prior to PG14 use the arrow syntax `(j->>0)\\:\\:integer` instead of `j[0]\\:\\:integer` and `j->>1` instead of `j[1]\\:\\:text`

**Alternative**

Serialization format:

```json
[
 {"column_a":1, "column_b":234},
 {"column_a":2, "column_b":345}
]
```

Query:

```sql
update test as t set column_a = c.column_a
from (
  select column_a, column_b
  from jsonb_to_recordset(?1::jsonb) as (column_a integer, column_b text)
) c 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

This approach - serialize complex dynamic data as JSON text then pass it as a single `String` parameter to a native query and let the query do the rest - is quite generic and works well in many different cases.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing similar. I was looking for passing a map or something similar.

Comment: Well, since the Java domain and the data domain are very different animals I think that having explicit control over the transition b/w them and who is doing what (who is best fit for the job) is much better than relying on magic.